# What is the best way to handle multiple sets of parameters passing to tests using TestNG and Allure?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, allure

I'm currently working on a project, where we have around ~30 test cases. We are using TestNG and Allure for reports. We faced the problem, where we want to pass multiple sets of parameters to the test case, so test will run multiple times, for each set of data. What is the best way to handle it?

Some of the tests need some parameters, and have different possibilities, like:

Test logging:
Step 1: Param A | Param B | Param C
Step 2: Param 1 | Param 2
And we want Test to run for each combination:
Test logging1: A1; Test logging2: A2; Test logging3: B1; Test logging4: B2, etc., etc. Of course, some tests don't have parameters, and some have plenty in several steps.

Currently, we have these parameters in class variables and tests using them, but only one set at a time, so we need to change it manually. What is a better approach to this?

We were trying using @Factory from TestNG, but in Allure alternative tests appear as Retries- it's not quite convenient.

I know it is possible to assign Parameters in testNG suite.xml but it doesn't seem... appropriate? I mean, this xml would be pretty big. I know there are a couple of ways to deal with it, but I want to hear some feedback from more experienced people, so if you faced something similar and got any advice, it would be great!

Comment: if i understood your 3 questions. You want to run one test case with different data?

Comment: Exactly, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: you could use data providers. Google "selenium data provider examples" and you'll find plenty of examples.